# Laravel - Error when try to submit a form

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form which updates a record however I am recieving the following error:

> Method App\Handling::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught InvalidArgumentException: Data missing

The `Handling` is my model.

This is my routes:

```
Route::get('/update-handling/{id}', 'HandlingController@edit');
Route::post('/update-handling/{id}', 'HandlingController@update')->name('postUpdateHandling');
```

The `get` works fine and returns me the `Handling` object correctly. When I try to update the form and go to `post` route returns me the error above.

And this is my `update` function:

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
      $name = $request->input('name');
      $handling = $request->input('handling-thermic');

      $thermic = 0;
      $superficial = 0;

      if ($handling == 0)
      {
        $thermic = 1;
      }
      else if ($handling == 1)
      {
        $superficial = 1;
      }

      $handling = Handling::find($id);

      $handling->u_name = $name;
      $handling->u_thermic = $thermic;
      $handling->u_superficial = $superficial;
      $handling->u_active = 1;
      $handling->save();

    }
```

My html form:

```
{!! Form::open(['id' => 'update-handling', 'url' => route('postUpdateHandling',['id' => $handling->id]), 'method' => 'post']) !!}
```

Comment: have you used the path for model?

Comment: Yes, in my controller I put use App\Handling; And I can comunicate with model to get and insert data, just return error in update function. @mayuriPansuriya

Comment: also post your html form code form action

Comment: Html doesn't throw exceptions, even when data is missing

Comment: I update the question with update form @KuldeepMishra .

Comment: I'd like to see the `Handling` model definition

Comment: Your `public function update()` should be returning a `return redirect()` or `return back()` or `return view()` etc; I think this causes an error if you have that omitted.

Comment: If I echo my variable before find() it print them @user3647971

Comment: If you `Log::info($handling);` before you save it, what do you get in the log file (storage/logs)? I see "Data missing" more often from Carbon when it can't parse a datetime string.

Comment: {{ Form::open(array('route'=>['postUpdateHandling', $handling->id], 'method' => 'POST')) }}

use this form action

Comment: Doesn't work too with this form action. @KuldeepMishra

Comment: show your `edit ` function

Answer (score 0):

your form should be :

```
    <form method="post" action="{{route('postUpdateHandling',['id'=>$handling->id])}}">
       ...

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

in your controller :

```
 use Session;

 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
       // first find record exists or not , if exits then update else redirect to 404 or home page

      $handling = Handling::find($id);
      if($handling){

      $name = $request->input('name');

      // added ternary condition for better syntax 

      $thermic = (int)$request->input('handling-thermic')==0 ? 1 : 0 ;
      $superficial =(int)$request->input('handling-thermic')==1 ? 1 : 0 ;

      $handling->u_name = $name;
      $handling->u_thermic = $thermic;
      $handling->u_superficial = $superficial;
      $handling->u_active = 1;
      $handling->save();
       return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Updated');          

      }else{
        // redirect to 404 or homepage
         return redirect('/home');
      }

    }
```

in your blade view add below snippet for display message :

```
@if (session()->has('success'))
    <h1>{{ session('success') }}</h1>
@endif
```

Comment: What data is missing? It might help to see the rest of the form. Are all the inputs named properly?